# Why does my preview script does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

here is the template i am using i tried to log the date also but it doesn't log

```
        {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date = $("#id_Date");
        $("#preview-date").val(date.val())
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to implement an event handler for updating the #preview-date value. and you need to show the error first then people can answer your problem.